# Checkmarx : Improper Error Handling in data access layer of web application

Tags: java, exception, checkmarx

I have a webapp with a controller layer, a service layer, and a data access layer.

Checkmarx complains about `improper error handling` when I call `getSingleResult` in my data access layer where methods look like this :

```
public FilterWorkflow getNextStatusesForAction(final Long currentStatus, final String actionRequested) {
    Query query = this.getEntityManager().createQuery(GET_NEXT_STATUSES_FOR_ACTION);
    query.setParameter("currentStatus_Id", currentStatus);
    query.setParameter("actionRequested", actionRequested);
    return (FilterWorkflow) query.getSingleResult();
}
```

This is called from the service layer like this :

```
@Override
@Transactional(value="txManager", rollbackFor = Exception.class)
public SomeFilter executeAction(SomeFilter bf, final String action requested) throws Exception {
    Long currentStatusID = bf.getFilteStatus().getTableId();
    FilterWorkflow fw = this.someDAO.getNextStatusesForAction(currentStatusID, actionRequested);

    return this.updateFilterStatus(fw, bf, actionRequested);
}
```

which gets called in the controller layer :

```
public String execute(SomeFilter bf, final String command) {
    try {
        bf = this.someService.executeAction(bf, command);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.info(e.getMessage());
        FacesUtil.addErrorMessage(this.msgApp.getMessage("error_message"));
        return null;
    }
    return null;
}
```

I think the exception is handled, because there is nothing more to do about the exceptions that `getSingleResult` can throw, other than displaying an error message to the user, and logging that error.

Am I missing something ?

Comment: It really does look weird. I will try to create a smaller sample and report it to Checkmarx.

Comment: I think the issue is raised because in a lot of query, Checkmarx is not very well with MVC.  Another thing, can be the too wide catch of the exception....

Comment: l0r3nz4cc10, did you evern get this resolved? I'm getting similar issues flagged by Checkmarx, as well. Kind of makes me wonder whether Checkmarx may have issues dealing with Spring projects.